# How to find the label names of an image in a custom dataset with Dataloader in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I am using this code to load the training data from a custom dataset, there are 14 classes i.e. 14 folders and each folder has 100 images.

```
data_loader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset_train,
    batch_size=args.batch_size,
    num_workers=args.num_workers,
    
)
```

I want to print the name of the class to which an image belongs. How do I do that?

Comment: It will depend on the implementation of the dataset class. How did you create `dataset_train`? Did you use [torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder)?

Comment: here is the complete implementation, line no:106 https://github.com/AnikChaudhuri/image-retrieval-transformers/blob/main/main.py

Comment: Looking at that implementation, there doesn't seem to be an obvious mechanism for getting the class names cleanly. The dataset is selected in [get_dataset](https://github.com/AnikChaudhuri/image-retrieval-transformers/blob/main/datasets/__init__.py#L6) and can be one of three different datasets, all inheriting [BaseDataset](https://github.com/AnikChaudhuri/image-retrieval-transformers/blob/dd90515a7481165277fbeb014c31aa699db91c13/datasets/base_dataset.py#L7). You'll probably need to modify the datasets to make class names available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create `dataset_train` using any of the classes listed [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html)? If yes, this could be your solution:

```py
class_names = {idx: cls for cls, idx in data_loader_train.dataset.class_to_idx.items()}
```

`data_loader_train.dataset` will return the original dataset it load (or iterate) from, and since the dataset is made with [those classes](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html), it has an attribute `class_to_idx` which is a dictionary mapping a class label (real class name) to its corresponding index. The above code will reverse that dictionary, helping you get the class name from the class index.

If you **only** want the class names out of the dataset, use:

```py
class_names = data_loader_train.dataset.classes
```

Hope it helps!